# Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my Rcode below:

```
wikipediaPage <-"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1500_metres_world_record_progression"
htmlContent <- getURL(wikipediaPage)
result <- readHTMLTable(htmlContent)

tableWR <- readHTMLTable(htmlContent, which = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tempTime = as.POSIXlt(tableWR$Time, format = "%M:%OS")

finalTable = data.frame(runTime = (tempTime$min * 60) + tempTime$sec, 
                        recordSet = as.Date(tableWR$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

p1 <- ggplot(data = finalTable, aes(x = recordSet, y = runTime))
p1 + geom_line()
```

Then I got an error saying

> Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Please update your post to make the code reproducible. Your code includes functions like `getURL()` which is not a base function in R. At the start of your code, include `library()` calls to the packages required for your code to work.

Comment: Nathan, please also format your question properly as per the [advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Did you *only* encounter the error at the last step? Are the contents of `tableWR` / `tempTime` / `finalTable` what you'd expect?